# Get Apache installation path via PHP in Windows environment

Tags: php, windows, apache, windows-10

How do I use PHP 8.0 to determine the Apache installation path in a Windows environment?

No: I know where it is *manually*, I need to do this *programmatically*.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Apache installation path"? And why should one require such information?

Comment: You can obviously write a script that performs exactly what you do "manually" to find the information you are looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing in `$_SERVER` and I had to resort to digging through `phpinfo()`. The following allows you to reuse `phpinfo()` as `$pinfo` if you need to find other bits of information. Additionally PHP does not support the JavaScript index style (e.g. `explode()[index]`) on I think 7.2 and older so anyone stuck on those older versions may have to re-code the two `explode` in to separate lines.

```
//If you need additional items you can refer ONCE to $pinfo:
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$pinfo = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT')
{
 //explode()[index] will not work on PHP ~7.2 and older
 echo explode('<', explode('>Server Root </td><td class="v">', $pinfo, 2)[1], 2)[0];
}
```